# pip3 present for Python 3.8 altough removed and purged

Tags: package-management, python

I am trying to reduce the number of python versions I am maintaining on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. Somehow pip3 always installed packages for Python 3.8 although `python3` defaults to Python 3.6 (even on using python3.8 I cannot get the packages).

I tried to remove pip3 entirely in an effort to have a clean reinstall. I tried to purge it but `pip3 --version` is still a recognized command.

```
panther@panther3:~$ sudo apt purge python3-pip  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3-pip' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
panther@panther3:~$ sudo rm -rf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip'  
panther@panther3:~$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Why is that and how do I get rid of pip3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to remove pip3
>
> .... how do I get rid of pip3?

When pip3 cannot be removed with `apt` it's usually because it was installed manually, or with `pip3`. I.e. only packages installed with apt ( or dpkg ) can be removed with `apt`.

Suggest : `$ pip3 uninstall pip` (or `$ sudo pip3 uninstall pip`)